# android How to show copy and paste context view in edittext in service window

Tags: android, service, copy, paste, android-inflate

1. I create popup window in service like this

   ```
   public class ChatService extends Service {
       WindowManager mWindowMgr;
       WindowManager.LayoutParams mWinMgrParam;
       View mView;

       @Override
       public void onCreate()
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_window, null);

           mWinMgrParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
           PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

           mWindowMgr = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
           mWindowMgr.addView(mView, mWinMgrParam);
       }

   }
   ```
2. But not open copy&paste context view in edittext and textview like this.
   please see this attachment img.
   string was selected but not popup "copy, paste" context view...

[image]

3. I want to show copy and paste popup in my service view. How to do that?
4. chat_service.xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvContents"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="@color/black_overlay_150"
       android:maxLines="50"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:textColor="@color/white"
       android:textIsSelectable="true" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:background="@color/green_light">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvNickName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:text="nickname"
           android:textSize="14sp" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/etUserInput"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:textSize="14sp" />
   ```
5. AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
> <service
>     android:permission="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"
>     android:enabled="true"
>     android:name=".talk.ChatService">
> </service>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Change in layout file `chat_window.xml`: add below property to your EditText

`android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Comment: it is already added. you can understand that. check attached image. text can be seleted.

Comment: I added xml in content

Comment: Which theme you are using? Try to use `@android:style/Theme.WithActionBar` OR `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: Try this option `editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);`

Comment: As per the documentation, content of `EditText` can always be selectable. How you are using: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#isTextSelectable()

Comment: select text is not problem. text is already selected. problem is not generate copy and paste popup window...

Comment: Is it because edittext and textview were run through the windowManager?